# How to send a separate default text every time text is sent via SMS service from android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have implemented the SMS service in my app. Now I can send SMS from within my app to a phone number, but I want the received text to have a separate message at the end to know that the text was sent using my app. Is that possible? If so then how? Below is my SendSMSActivity and ReceiveSMSActivity. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks :)

**SendSMSActivity**

```
package com.golo.acer.mrestro4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SendSmsActivity extends Activity {

    Button sendSmsBtn;
    EditText toPhoneNumber;
    EditText smsMessageET;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_sms);

        sendSmsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        toPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
        smsMessageET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

        sendSmsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendSms();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendSms() {
        String toPhone = toPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
        String smsMessage = smsMessageET.getText().toString();

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(toPhone, null, smsMessage, null, null);

            Toast.makeText(this, "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void goToInbox(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SendSmsActivity.this, ReceiveSMSActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void moveToSmsActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SmsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**ReceiveSMSActivity**

```
package com.golo.acer.mrestro4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;


public class ReceiveSMSActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    private static ReceiveSMSActivity inst;
    ArrayList<String> smsMessageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView smsListView;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    public static ReceiveSMSActivity instance() {
        return inst;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        inst = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_sms);

        smsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SMSList);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsMessageList);
        smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        smsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        refreshSmsInbox();
    }

    public void refreshSmsInbox() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
        int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
        int timeMillis = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("date");
        Date date = new Date(timeMillis);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        String dateText = format.format(date);

        if(indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        do {
             String str = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) + " at "
                     + "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + dateText + "\n";
             arrayAdapter.add(str);
        } while(smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    public void updateList(final String smsMessage) {
        arrayAdapter.insert(smsMessage, 0);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        try {
            String[] smsMessages = smsMessageList.get(position).split("\n");
            String address = smsMessages[0];
            String smsMessage = "";

            for(int i = 1; i < smsMessages.length; i++) {
                smsMessage += smsMessages[i];
            }

            String smsMessageStr = address + "\n";
            smsMessageStr += smsMessage;
            Toast.makeText(this, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void goToCompose(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ReceiveSMSActivity.this, SendSmsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**activity_send_sms.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#ffcecbff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Compose New Message"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneNumber"
        android:text="Phone Number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
        android:text="SMS Message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSMS"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />


    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnInbox"
        android:text="Inbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="goToInbox"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What about simply concatenating the text to `smsMessage` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can concatenate `smsMessage`  variable with the text you want and its done.

For eg: In your sendSMS function:

```
String smsMessage = smsMessageET.getText().toString();
smsMessage+="\n\nBy My Application";
```

I hope this will help you , Feel free to comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped! :)  I do have another problem. Is there any way to ensure that the text is in fact sent using the app and not that some other person typed it by themselves and sent it? Perhaps changing the color of text or something?

Comment: You can achieve this but for this you have to use custom adapter to display the sms list and in one view it should have 2 controls , one TextView for sms and second TextView for signature text and as these are android controls so we can set the properties like setTextColor , setTextSize etc. So you just have to search on making suctom adapter for listview and thats it :)

Comment: I'm a little confused and short in time. I've added the xml layout in edit. Can you please edit the code to add the signature text as "Sent via M-Restro App" with a slightly bold font? Thanks :)

Comment: bold and red color*

Comment: It can not be done in your main layout , you have to make custom adapter and that adapter will have its own custom layout. I think you must refer this link for reference : http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-2-custom-listview/. Please check this and make the adapter in this way in your program.And then and then only you will be able to make what you want. Sorry but i can not do whole code here. I hope you understand :) but plz refer this you will get better idea , in addition you will learn something new and that is most important in live applications in market. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks I will look into it :)